# textview on Android cut off

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    style="@style/Fondo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/descripcion"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:src="@drawable/proyecto_logo1_aux" />

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_rounded_corners"
    android:weightSum="19.0" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/TableRow05"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_rounded_corners" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/levadura_data_Nombre"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#311b10"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/TableRow04"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/levadura_lab"
            android:textColor="#311b10" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/levadura_data_lab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#311b10" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/TableRow03"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/levadura_productid"
            android:textColor="#311b10" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/levadura_data_idproduct"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#311b10" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/TableRow02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/levadura_tipo"
            android:textColor="#311b10" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/levadura_data_tipo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#311b10" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/TableRow01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/levadura_forma"
            android:textColor="#311b10" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/levadura_data_forma"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#311b10" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/levadura_floculacion"
            android:textColor="#311b10" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/levadura_data_floculacion"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#311b10" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/levadura_celulas"
            android:textColor="#311b10" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/levadura_data_celulas"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#311b10" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/levadura_aten_min"
            android:textColor="#311b10" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/levadura_data_aten_min"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#311b10" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/TableRow06"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/levadura_aten_max"
            android:textColor="#311b10" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/levadura_data_aten_max"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#311b10" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/TableRow07"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView04"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/levadura_temp_min"
            android:textColor="#311b10" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/levadura_data_temp_min"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#311b10" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/TableRow08"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView03"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/levadura_temp_max"
            android:textColor="#311b10" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/levadura_data_temp_max"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#311b10" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/TableRow09"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="8.0" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView07"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/levadura_mejor"
            android:textColor="#311b10" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/levadura_data_mejor"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="marquee" 
            android:textColor="#311b10" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_rounded_corners"
    android:weightSum="1.0" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/TableRow11"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView05"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/levadura_notas"
            android:textColor="#311b10"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/TableRow17"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.9" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/levadura_data_notas"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:textColor="#311b10"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And couldn't show all text on `android:id="@+id/levadura_data_mejor"`.
I don't know why.
For example, I do `setText("Trappist Belgian Ales, Dubbles, Tripels and speciality Ales)`, but only is showing `["Trappist Belgian Ales, Dubbles, Tripels"]`
I appreciate your help. Thx

Comment: what do you mean show all text? can you make it more clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use android:layout_weight as shown below:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView07"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/levadura_mejor"
        android:textColor="#311b10"
       android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/levadura_data_mejor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee" 
        android:text="Trappist Belgian Ales, Dubbles, Tripels and speciality Ales"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="#311b10" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
android:singleLine="false"
```

add the above line.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really shure if this is solving Your problem, I don´t know If You want to make a line break or if You want to scroll the text, if it is longer than the view. But if You want to scroll it, set the following parameters:

```
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="-1"
        android:singleLine="true"
```

And in Your Java code class, You have to set Your TextView selected:

```
        yourTextView.setSelected(true);
```